# How to programmatically change x-position attribute of md-menu?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

[md-menu](https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu) has the x-position = "before | after" attribute. I want to change the attribute dynamically. So far, I've tried

```
<md-menu [attr.x-position]="isLeftToRightLanguage()? 'after': 'before'" ... >
```

That didn't work (no errors). I also tried without the square brackets which got me the MdMenuInvalidPositionX error in the browser console.

```
<md-menu x-position="isLeftToRightLanguage()? 'after': 'before'" ... >
```

PS: isLeftToRightLanguage() is a method in the component that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud be using `mdMenuTriggerFor` property as below

```
<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="clicked($event)">
  <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>
  <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item disabled>
  <span>Check voicemail</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
  <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

Alternatively you can use `positionX` and `positionY` as well and handle the event position as below,

```
clicked(event){
     console.log(event);
  }
```

you should be using `event.screenX` and `event.screenY` to get the clicked X and Y positions

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XbDYOYMapAioCtsrWye3?p=preview)**

Comment: md-menu has an attribute x-position which I want to change dynamically based on a click event elsewhere - which has nothing to do with the trigger button. Your answer is a general md-menu usage example. I don't want the clicked positions either. Please refer https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu for info on the x-position and y-position attributes of md-menu.